# SPFieldLookup "Add a column to show each of these additional fields" programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

[Additional fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW5Kn.png)

I want to get this list when I have a `SPFieldLookup` convert from a `SPField`, and additionally edit to show more fields. Has anyone experienced this before? Please, help me.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: SPList olistsubGoc;
foreach (SPField oField in olistsubGoc.Fields)
{
   SPFieldLookup templk = (SPFieldLookup)oField;
}
This is my code, im trying to add the additional field from oField to the templk to add it to a new list

Comment: you may get addition fields for lookup field by `templk.ID`, `templk.Title` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (SPField oSPFieldV2 in olistsubGoc.Fields)
                    {
                        if (oSPFieldV2.StaticName.Contains(oField.StaticName + "_x003a_"))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (olistsub.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName(oSPFieldV2.StaticName) == null)
                                {
                                    SPField tmep = olistsub.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName(oField.StaticName);
                                    string depLookUp = olistsub.Fields.AddDependentLookup(oSPFieldV2.StaticName, tmep.Id);
                                    SPFieldLookup fieldDepLookup = (SPFieldLookup)olistsub.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(depLookUp);
                                    fieldDepLookup.LookupField = oSPFieldV2.StaticName.Replace(oField.StaticName + "_x003a_", "");
                                    fieldDepLookup.Update();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

This is the solution for my question that i find out.